# How to play articulate html file from localserver in flutter?

Tags: connection-refused, localserver, flutter-inappwebview

I had tried this code .I had used inappwebview for this . I had given INTERNET,ACEESS_NETWORK_STATE,BLUETHOOTH,WAKE_LOCK,WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permissions in .XML file .I got this error "localhost:8080/connection refused".

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ABQu.jpg)

Comment: Please paste the code as text instead of an image.